# Ищу плагин для VSCode который отображает дерево вложенных функций и методов в коде

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите пожалуйста название плагина который отображает дерево вложенных функций и методов в коде. Как изображено на скрине.

[image: Пример работы плагина]

Comment: Тоже его ищу, если ты уже нашел, скажи как называется

Comment: стоит еще уточнить для какого ЯП. `Outline` вас не устраивает, который идет из коробки в левом нижнем углу?

Answer (score 0):

Это Guidelines в Flutter. Зайдите в настройки, пропишите flutter guidelines и нажмите чекбокс, после перезагрузки все появиться. Вот скрин [image: Настройки]Вот ссылка еще интересных настроек https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAmOt5_fMtU

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Вы не уточнили, что это расширение `dart`. Данный функционал не подходит для любых файлов.